# Find centroid POI for 2 or more places by travel time or distance using multiple modes of transport

Tags: gis, geo-location, google-maps

I want to find a mutually convenient POI between two or more places so that everyone drives or goes by public transport or bicycle a similar distance or travel time.

I've done a Google Search: find a restaurant halfway. I've browsed the following web apps:

- [MeetWays: Meet in the Middle - Find a Halfway Point](https://www.meetways.com/)
- [Whatshalfway.com - Find great places to meet or stop halfway](https://www.whatshalfway.com/)

The problem with MeetWays is it doesn't support multiple locations nor by travel time or distance.

The problem with Whatshalfway is it doesn't support individual settings for transport for each place nor does it support public transport.

Bonus points if it can filter restaurants by availability of booking networks such as Quandoo or TheFork.

Comment: What OS should the application run on? How much are you willing to pay for it?

Comment: A webapp would be best so mobile web. Android is ok as well as is windows.